# Items in RecyclerView are repeating

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an Android project in which I am using RecyclerView. The count of the items in recycler view are correct but the items are getting repeated after certain interval. I have checked on Internet for the solution and tried using them but it did not help me.

Java code of the fragment is as follows:

```
package com.example.laundry1app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;
public class AllProductsFragment extends Fragment {
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private ArrayList<AllProductsData> data;
    private TextView products;
    private View view;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FloatingActionButton add, cart;
    private boolean flag;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_products, container, false);
        progress = view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        add = view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        cart = view.findViewById(R.id.cart);
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("admins");
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if (Objects.equals(snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail())) {
                            flag = true;
                            add.show();
                            add.setEnabled(true);
                            cart.hide();
                            cart.setEnabled(false);
                            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    if (getFragmentManager() != null) {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), AddProductActivity.class));
                                        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finish();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!flag) {
                        add.hide();
                        add.setEnabled(false);
                        cart.show();
                        cart.setEnabled(true);
                        cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), CartActivity.class));
                                Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finish();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
        products = view.findViewById(R.id.products);
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("products");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                data.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    data.add(new AllProductsData(snapshot.child("english").getValue(String.class), snapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class)));

                }
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (data.isEmpty()) {
                    products.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    products.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }//
                recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new AllProductsAdapter(data));
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Code of data class is:

```
package com.example.laundry1app;

public class AllProductsData {
    private String english, url;

    AllProductsData(String english, String url) {
        this.english = english;
        this.url = url;

    }

    public String getEnglish() {
        return english;
    }

    public void setEnglish(String english) {
        this.english = english;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

The Java code of adapter is as below:

```
package com.example.laundry1app;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;

class AllProductsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<com.example.laundry1app.AllProductsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<AllProductsData> data;
    private DatabaseReference reference, databaseReference;
    private boolean flag;
    private Double p;
    AllProductsAdapter(ArrayList<AllProductsData> data) {
        setHasStableIds(true);
        this.data = data;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_products, viewGroup, false));
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int i) {
        viewHolder.english.setText(data.get(i).getEnglish());
        viewHolder.quantity.setText(viewHolder.quantity.getText().toString());
        GlideApp.with(viewHolder.image.getContext()).load(data.get(i).getUrl()).into(viewHolder.image);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(viewHolder.spinner.getContext(),R.array.Services, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        viewHolder.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("admins");
            reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if (Objects.equals(snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail())) {
                            flag = true;
                            viewHolder.add.setEnabled(false);
                            viewHolder.add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.quantity.setEnabled(false);
                            viewHolder.quantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.spinner.setEnabled(false);
                            viewHolder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!flag) {
                        viewHolder.add.setEnabled(true);
                        viewHolder.add.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/cart");
                        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    if (Objects.equals(snapshot.child("english").getValue(), data.get(i).getEnglish())  && Objects.equals(snapshot.child("quantity").getValue(String.class), viewHolder.quantity.getText().toString())) {
                                        viewHolder.add.setEnabled(false);
                                        viewHolder.add.setText(R.string.added);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            }
                        });
                        viewHolder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if (viewHolder.english.length() == 0 ) {
                                    viewHolder.english.requestFocus();
                                    viewHolder.english.setError("This Is A Required Field");
                                } else if (viewHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem() == "Wash" || viewHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem() == "Laundry" || viewHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem() == "Steam Press" || viewHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem() == "Wash + Steam Press"){
                                    viewHolder.spinner.requestFocus();
                                    Toast.makeText(viewHolder.spinner.getContext(), "Select a service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else {
                                    databaseReference = reference.push();
                                    databaseReference.child("english").setValue(data.get(i).getEnglish());
                                    databaseReference.child("quantity").setValue(viewHolder.quantity.getText().toString());
                                    databaseReference.child("image").setValue(data.get(i).getUrl());
                                    databaseReference.child("service").setValue(viewHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                    if (viewHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Wash")) {
                                        p = Double.parseDouble(viewHolder.quantity.getText().toString()) * 5;

                                    } else if (viewHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Laundry")) {
                                        p = Double.parseDouble(viewHolder.quantity.getText().toString()) * 8;

                                    } else if (viewHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Steam Press")) {
                                        p = Double.parseDouble(viewHolder.quantity.getText().toString()) * 3;

                                    } else if (viewHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Wash + Steam Press")) {
                                        p = Double.parseDouble(viewHolder.quantity.getText().toString()) * 7;

                                    }
                                    databaseReference.child("price").setValue(p);
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView english, quantity;
        private Button add;
        Spinner spinner;
        private ImageView image;
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.english = itemView.findViewById(R.id.english);
            this.quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            this.add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add);
            this.spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.typeof_service);
            this.image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me resolve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO approach to fetch data in Adapter is really bad. Try to handle data somewhere else and just pass it to adapter, then based on data you set in adapter you will generate views for it. If pushed data changes you should replace it in adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged. Adapter should not handle any logic of fetching / getting data for its views, nor should it handle references to Database etc. When you fix this one, I hope all of your problems with repeating views will disappear

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that your items have a stable id (`setHasStableId(true)`) but you are not returning a a stable/unique id for your items, instead you are returning `super.getItemId()` which returns `NO_ID` for every position.

See documentation of [setHasStableId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#hasStableIds()) and [getItemId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getitemid).

Answer (score 0):

1) Your class AllProductsData does not contain an unique ID for each item, so you might want to add:

```
public class AllProductsData {
    private int id;
    private String english, url;
    //...
```

2 Your getItemId method is not looking for an Id in the AllProductsData List instead a method in the super class (which is: RecyclerView.Adapter)
after adding the id to the class, your getItemId should look like:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return data[position].id;
}
```